# Proxy Auto config (PAC) exception

Tags: proxy, pac

I want to configure a proxy pac file that has the same list of exception as the ones I have on IE -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN settings -> Advanced and after I can see the exception in the part that reads:

"Do not use proxy server for addresses beginning with:"
"*.blabla.com;"

I've tried using DnsDomainIs, shExpMatch (example below) and it does not go through.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.blabla.com")) { return "DIRECT"; }
        ...
```

The PAC file is working fine for the rest. Can anybody see what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with this http://code.google.com/p/pacparser/.

Answer (score 1):

As it should be a regex, you should maybe do a

```
.*\.blabla\.com
```

Comment: Thank you DOM. Seems to be almost working. I had a typo. My main problem with these files is I don't know how to debug the file. Do you have any idea how to debug it?

Comment: I dont' think you can debug these scripts. Type a new condition, test it, and add the next rule, then test it again, it is my proposition !

Comment: I found out how to fix it by trial and error. You can debug it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621004/how-to-debug-a-javascript-proxy-pac-file-used-for-ie-proxy-settings